# why 2 mysql queries did not work (just after one, another)

Tags: php, mysql

i am working a webkitmedia software house where i going to develop a website. i write 2 mysql queries in 2 rows and i have seen that 1st query did not execute while 2nd executed. if i commented 2nd query than 1st work. i have solved it with other method but really want to know this behavior of mysql.

2 queries are as follow

```
$query1 = "insert into users_meta values('','$id','hide_profile_option','$hide_profile_option')";
$query2 = "insert into users_meta values('','$id','hide_profile_date','$hide_profile_date')";
```

In this case `$query2` executed while if i commented `$query2` then `$query1` executed and insertion made in table.

can anyone tell me why this happens in MYSQL.?

Comment: You are not executing anything here, you are just defining strings. What does the complete code look like?

Comment: provide whole code if you have actually executed the above queries & how..just bubbles in the air

Comment: code is in simple function (7-8 lines) (using codeigniter).

Comment: mysql functions are deprecated. Please use PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: use mysqli_* ..can you tell us if you execute query one by one it's being executed??

Comment: yes it is executing. like if i commented $query1 than $query2 excuted or vise versa... i just want to know why this is. i have did work already.

Comment: see your php or sql error log what does it say or use if(mysqli_query($query)) if not successful then get mysqli_error..and please do let us know too

Comment: Can you please give a bit more informations about the users_meta table structure ?

Comment: columns are as (id,user_id,meta_key,meta_value) where id is auto increment.

Comment: @DevLakshman i will must give in your knowledge.

Comment: And user_id is not a primary key in the users_meta table?

Comment: Why did this get 2 upvotes?